# How do I send a silent push to my browser's Javascript app?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am using Firebase but I'm unsure it is relevant.

I am trying to send a silent push to my app running in the browser (it's a JS/React Single Page Application), and according to the Firebase FCM documentation, all I have to do is send a message with a "data" key.

However, this doesn't work for me: if my message doesn't have a "notification" key, it is not received by the browser.

To test this, I run these 2 curl commands:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<MYKEY>"  -X POST -d '{ "data": { "foo": "1","bar": "2"},"to" : "<TOKEN>", "notification": { "data" : "Some data" } }' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<MYKEY>"  -X POST -d '{ "data": { "foo": "1","bar": "2"},"to" : "<TOKEN>" }' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

The first one makes it to the browser when the app is "open", and will go to the notification center when the app is "closed" (either tab closed, or browser closed).

The second one never reaches anything (but the response to the curl call gives "success":1, "failure":0)

What am I doing wrong?
Is this just not supported by WebPush? I read contradictory info online.

There are cases when silent push is really useful to update client state in the browser. For example, if I build a chat app with channels/groups, I'd like to be able to send updates about the state of the chat to the client without having a user visible notification: I don't want the user to see an explicit "over the top" notification when there is an update to the chat group's participants for example: I just want to update it in the UI of the browser, especially if the app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by registering a handler with Firebase's setBackgroundMessageHandler() in my service worker.

Firebase's doc states that this is only required for background processing of "data only" pushes (ie silent), but it turns out that it seems required for foreground processing too (even if your handler does nothing.)

Once I registered my dummy handler, I started receiving my silent pushes into the app in the foreground.